# Find record not joined with SQL and a specific id

Tags: mysql

I have two table, A and B, and a join table.
For an item of B table, let's say with id = 1, I want to find all the records in A that are not joined to this B item.

I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN A_B ON A.id = A_B.A_id 
  WHERE A_B.A_id IS NULL 
  AND A_B.B_id = 1;
```

But it gives me no records while it should...

Any idea to fix it ?

Comment: Can you share what your table looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put `A_B.B_id = 1` in your ON condition instead of `where`

```
SELECT * 
FROM A LEFT JOIN A_B 
ON A.id = A_B.A_id AND A_B.B_id = 1
WHERE A_B.A_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Many thanks ! That's it ! I will approve your answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could also phrase your query using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM A_B ab WHERE a.id = ab.A_id AND ab.B_id = 1);
```